# Multiple operation on different columns in single Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, list-comprehension

Multiple operation on different columns in single Dataframe

I have a dataframe like mentioned below:

```
PNO         VAL1    VAL2    VAL3    VAL4    CNT
100         45      15      35      98      1
100         25      85      24      65      1
100         85      74      74      75      1
100         98      36      36      84      1
100         74      54      54      52      0
2000        36      21      21      41      1
2000        54      25      45      52      1
2000        21      85      25      63      1
2000        58      98      85      89      0
30000       96      35      66      87      1
30000       32      24      87      54      1
30000       35      58      41      56      1
30000       24      96      52      25      1
```

I want to create a result dataframe which will have following operation on different columns:

for Every PNO

1. Find Max Value of VAL1 Column
2. Find Min Value of VAL2 Column
3. Find Last Value of VAL3 and VAL4 Column
4. Find Sum of CNT Column

Result:

```
PNO         VAL1    VAL2    VAL3    VAL4    CNT
100         98      15      54      52      4
2000        58      21      85      89      3
30000       96      24      52      25      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `agg` with `dict` of rules on each column

```
In [32]: (df.groupby('PNO', as_index=False)
            .agg({'VAL1': 'max', 'VAL2': 'min', 
                  'VAL3': 'last', 'VAL4': 'last', 'CNT': 'sum'})
             )
Out[32]:
     PNO  VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4  CNT
0    100    98    15    54    52    4
1   2000    58    21    85    89    3
2  30000    96    24    52    25    4
```